# How do I stack labels in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I am writing my first Swing app and I'm having some trouble stacking labels in code.

I have the following right now

[image: First Swing app]

I would like "Enter the name of the repo and the name of the" to be above "owner of that repo to search for open issues." so the window isn't so wide.

Here's my code:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private Boolean submitted = false;

    public MainFrame(String title) {
        super(title);


        // Set layout manager
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // Create components
        JPanel panOuter = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel panLeft = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        panLeft.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        JPanel panRight = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panRight.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        JPanel panBottom = new JPanel();
        panBottom.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        JPanel panTop = new JPanel();
        panTop.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        JPanel panTopTop = new JPanel();
        panTopTop.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        JPanel panTopBottom = new JPanel();
        panTopBottom.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        // Add components to content panel
        panOuter.add(panLeft, BorderLayout.WEST);
        panOuter.add(panRight, BorderLayout.EAST);
        panOuter.add(panBottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panOuter.add(panTop, BorderLayout.NORTH);


        JLabel lblTop1 = new JLabel("Enter the name of the repo and the name of the\n", JLabel.CENTER);
        JLabel lblTop2 = new JLabel("owner of that repo to search for open issues.\n", JLabel.CENTER);
        JLabel lblLeft = new JLabel("Repo", JLabel.CENTER);
        JLabel lblRight = new JLabel("Owner", JLabel.CENTER);

        JTextField txtLeft = new JTextField("Hello", 10);
        JTextField txtRight = new JTextField("World", 10);

        JButton btnBottom = new JButton("Submit!");

        panLeft.add(lblLeft, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panLeft.add(txtLeft, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        panRight.add(lblRight, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panRight.add(txtRight, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        panBottom.add(btnBottom);
        panTopTop.add(lblTop1);
        panTopBottom.add(lblTop2);
        panTop.add(panTopTop, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panTop.add(panTopBottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        this.setContentPane(panOuter);
        this.pack();

        btnBottom.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(!submitted)
                    btnBottom.setText(txtLeft.getText());
                else 
                    btnBottom.setText(txtRight.getText());
                submitted = !submitted;
            }

        });
    }

}
```

I tried to make a panel that has a `NORTH` and `SOUTH` component of labels, but it didn't work.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Thanks,
erip

Comment: You should try a GridLayout()

Comment: Or use a `GridBagLayout` if you don't want ALL the components to have the same width/height

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using a `GridBagLayout`...

```
JPanel panTop = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
panTop.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
//JPanel panTopTop = new JPanel();
//panTopTop.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
//JPanel panTopBottom = new JPanel();
//panTopBottom.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

//...

//panTopTop.add(lblTop1);
//panTopBottom.add(lblTop2);
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
panTop.add(lblTop1, gbc);
panTop.add(lblTop2, gbc);
//panTop.add(panTopBottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

[image: GridBagLayout]

See [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details

Now, you could get really sneaky and use a `JTextArea`...

[image: TextArea]

```
JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(1, 20);
ta.setText("Enter the name of the repo and the name of the owner of that repo to search for open issues.");
ta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
ta.setLineWrap(true);
ta.setBorder(null);
ta.setFont(UIManager.getFont("Label.font"));
ta.setOpaque(false);
ta.setFocusable(false);
ta.setEditable(false);

//JLabel lblTop1 = new JLabel("<html>Enter the name of the repo and the name of the owner of that repo to search for open issues", JLabel.CENTER);
//JLabel lblTop2 = new JLabel("owner of that repo to search for open issues.\n", JLabel.CENTER);
//...
//panTopTop.add(lblTop1);
//panTopBottom.add(lblTop2);
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
panTop.add(ta, gbc);
```

Or even just use Swing's HTML support...

[image: HTML layout]

```
JLabel lblTop1 = new JLabel("<html><p align='center'>Enter the name of the repo and the name of the owner of that repo to search for open issues</p>", JLabel.CENTER);
panOuter.add(lblTop1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html this explains it all.

Comment: Phenomenal answer. Thank you, @MadProgrammer